# SSH Key Agent In Startup

Tags: ssh, startup-applications, gnome-keyring

In my Startup Applications, 'SSH Key Agent GNOME Keyring: SSH Agent' is checked. I wonder if it should remain like this. What is it useful for?

Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, OS type 64-bit

Answer (score 2):

From the ssh-agent man page:

> ssh-agent is a program to hold private keys used for public key
> authentication.  Through use of environment variables the agent can be
> located and automatically used for authentication when logging in to
> other machines using ssh(1).

Further useful information:

1. [What's the purpose of ssh-agent?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/72552/559660) In depth look at ssh-agent from our colleagues at Unix and Linux.
2. [How To Set up SSH Keys on a Linux / Unix System](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys-on-linux-unix/) General information on the use of SSH keys with a section devoted to ssh-agent.

Comment: This is good, concise explanation of ssh-agent, but it doesn't mention anything about including it in start up applications, what the pros and cons of that might be.